# How to configure AWS LightSail WordPress instance to map as example.com/blog

Tags: wordpress, apache, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have create a AWS LightSail WordPress instance. I tried all the possible config available to run WordPress in sub directory in the above mentioned Instance. Now I briefing it to simple. I want the above said instance to map to `example.com/blog` How we should achieve this. Any config to be done in DNS also welcomed! I wholeheartedly thank you for helping me!

Comment: Need more information on server architecture, you did not mention whether it's a bitnami wp image or simple lamp ubuntu server, except for tag you have added.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

Please follow the next steps to move wordpress from `/` to `/blog`.

1. Your `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-prefix.conf` should look like this

   ```
   Alias /blog/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/"
   Alias /blog "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

   Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
   ```
2. Edit the following in `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf`

   From: `#RewriteBase /wordpress/`
   To:  `RewriteBase /blog/`

   From: `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`
   To: `RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]`
3. Edit the following in `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php`

   From:

   ```
   define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
   define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
   ```

   To:

   ```
   define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog');
   define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog');
   ```
4. Finally restart apache:

   ```
   $ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
   ```